# Powershell - Where Clause unexpected behavior?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, where-clause

I have a complex script that evaluates "attributes" from a web service.
I build a list of all attributes and information about them in a list called **$global:attributes** and determine if they are single/multivalue value and are references.

Below is a snippet:

```
#Build the object
$obj = new-object object
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AttributeName -Value "Applications"
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsReference -Value $true
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsMultiValued -Value $true
$global:attributes = $obj
```

Now the following commands return "true" right?

```
(($global:attributes | where { $_.AttributeName -eq "Applications" }).IsReference -eq $true)
(($global:attributes | where { $_.AttributeName -eq "Applications" }).IsMultiValued -eq $true)
```

So why does the given function below doesn't evaluate as expected? Is it because I am invoking the where clause in a nested if statement?

```
Function doTest($key)
{
    if (($global:attributes | where { $_.AttributeName -eq $key}).IsReference -eq $true)
    {
        write-host "$key is of type Reference"
        if (($global:attributes | where { $_.AttributeName -eq $key}).IsMulitValued -eq $true)
        {
            write-host "$key is multivalued"
        }
        else {
            write-host "$key is single value"
        }
    } else {
        if (($global:attributes | where { $_.AttributeName -eq $key}).IsMultiValued -eq $true)
        {
            write-host "$key is Multivalue other"
        } else {
            write-host "$key is single value other"
        }
    }
}
```

This command
`doTest -key "Applications"` returns

```
Applications is of type Reference
Applications is single value
```

Should be multivalued, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code above... "IsMulitValued" instead of "IsMultiValued". When I changed that and ran it locally it produced your expected output.

Comment: I hate being dyslexic :(